# How to determine cordova/ionic JS vs ES5 or ES6?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have always just coded in Javascript and a bit of JQuery.  Over the last 2 years I am constantly reading about JS vs ES5 vs ES6 and am seeing a lot of the terminology move to ESx.  Also note I never had any formal education in programming and am completely self taught by way "need to get it done"

I have read wikipedia and other publications but honestly I am still a bit confused and now I need to get to the bottom of it because I am trying to minify/uglify my files and the process to do so is breaking and outputting 9 byte files of "undefined".  However, most all of the documentation on minify/uglify are referring to ES5 or ES6 which is confusing me on how I need to fix my code so the minify/uglify will work.

My project is built with Cordova 8.0/Ionic v1 and deploy to Android (cordova-android 7.1.1) and iPhone (cordova-ios 4.5.1) - thus I am not fully certain which version of JS I am using.  How can I determine what my project is using and know if its ES5 vs ES6...or other...so I can properly clean it up for minify and uglify?

Comment: ES5 and ES6 refers to ECMA Script version. ECMA Script is the standard on which Javascript is based. The version and the support on the standard depends on the javascript engine you are using. Not all engines implements the last version. The ES5 is the 2015 release of Javascript it still can run on all the browsers and nodejs for example. ES6 is some "tag" that indicate all the other specification releases after 2015, with new features.

Comment: Note that ES5 and ES6 are both JS ("JS vs ES5 vs ES6" is a bit weird statement in this regard). They are just different versions of implementation, you can perfectly have ES5 and ES6 syntax in the same file, it will still be JS. What changes is the support. Some minifiers/uglifiers will not support ES6 syntax though (in my version on uglifyjs, arrow functions don't work for example), which one are you using?

Comment: So an example of your code, that can reproduce the issue, with the exact error it would be helpful to understand your issue.

Comment: Plain 'javascript' is actually ES3! ES5 and ES6 just add new features to the language, but you don't have to use those features.

Comment: Thanks everyone...this is helping me get closer.  I guess it would just be easier if they called it JS5 and JS6...easy to understand that JS6 would have new features that JS5 doesn't have.  But when JS is both a subset of ES5 and ES6 it makes it a bit more confusing.  Other languages don't have this issue...perl is perl, python is python, php is php...but just JS is ES5 while ES5 is not necessarily JS, apparently it could also be JScript or other flavors.

Comment: @Kaddath - I was trying to use 'cordova-uglify' and it hosed a lot of my files.  I had to rebuild them all.  I am also now looking at `cordova-minify-v2` as well.  But I need to clean my code up first or I will continue to outputted files with simply a single word of `undefined` in them.  I need a preparser or validator that will help me understand where things are breaking before actually trying to minify/uglify things.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript, as seen in browsers is an implementation of [ECMAScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript), or "ES". Every once in a while, a new version of ES is specified, adding new functionality to the language, objects you have access to etc. For example, here's how [Wikipedia summarizes ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_-_ECMAScript_2015):

> The 6th edition, officially known as ECMAScript 2015, was finalized in June 2015. This update adds significant new syntax for writing complex applications, including classes and modules, but defines them semantically in the same terms as ECMAScript 5 strict mode. Other new features include iterators and for/of loops, Python-style generators, arrow functions, binary data, typed arrays, collections (maps, sets and weak maps), promises, number and math enhancements, reflection, proxies (metaprogramming for virtual objects and wrappers) and template literals. The complete list is extensive.

Now then, which of these features are implemented in the "JavaScript" that your browser provides to you is another story. It's quite complicated actually – [here's a table you can refer to regarding ES6 features](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), for example.

So in short, when you are writing a Cordova app or a website, you are using JavaScript, and most of the time it's safe to use any ES5 features you read about. For ES6 features, check the table I linked above. Since you're using Cordova / Ionic, you'll need to look at mobile browsers the most.

P.S. if you *really* want to use an ES6 or even ES7 feature that is currently not implemented in a browser you need to support, you might have some luck using [Babel](https://babeljs.io). It's a JavaScript "preprocessor"; that is, it takes your code, and transforms it to something that might work in older browsers better; the same way minifying keeps your code the same, just makes it smaller.