# Inconsistent behavior with Map.entries

Tags: cordova, ecmascript-6, meteor, cordova-plugins, es6-map

When I run the following code in dev console, I get the expected response:

```
const map = new Map();
map.set(1, "one");
map.set(2, "two");
map.set(3, "three");

for (const [key, value] of map.entries()) {
    console.log(`The value for key ${key} is ${value}`);
}
```

returns:

```
The value for key 1 is one
The value for key 2 is two
The value for key 3 is three
```

However, when I run the exact same code in a different browser environment, specifically inside a  Cordova app, I'm getting the response:

```
Uncaught TypeError: map.entries is not a function or its return value is not iterable
```

The following code without the `.entries()` still works in that environment.

```
for (const [key, value] of map) {
    console.log(`The value for key ${key} is ${value}`);
}
```

I am still able to successfully call map.entries(), which returns the correct response of MapIterator `{1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three'}`. It is when it's in the for ... of statement that is the issue.

Cordova Android userAgent: `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 13; sdk_gphone64_arm64 Build/TE1A.220922.033; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/103.0.5060.71 Mobile Safari/537.36' Working browser userAgent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36`

Cordova iOS user agent `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 17_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148`

Is there a possibility that the the for...of function does not support MapIterator in certain cases?

For more context:
This issue seems to be specific to Cordova and there is already a github [issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/11968) linked.

Comment: See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries#browser_compatibility) for the browser compatibility table for `map.entries()`.

Comment: This might help answer the question regarding Cordova: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55420547/3196753

Comment: It seems strange, that the `iterator` would be supported but not `entries()`, because according to the compatibility table, most browsers started supporting `entries()` and the `iterator` at the same time. And if not, the support for the `iterator` started even later than for `entries()` ...

Comment: Furthermore, all major browsers (desktop and mobile) are supporting the `Map` class and `entries` function at least since late 2014/early 2015. I'm not an expert with cordova, but as far as I know, it utilizes the underlying system's browser component. So unless you are running your code on an extremly outdated device this error should not be happening. What browser/version is running on that device? Can to get the useragen string?

Comment: I want to emphasize that in the problematic environment, I am still able to successfully call map.entries(), which returns the correct response of `MapIterator {1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three'}`. It is when it's in the for ... of statement that is the issue.

Comment: Cordova userAgent: `'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 13; sdk_gphone64_arm64 Build/TE1A.220922.033; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/103.0.5060.71 Mobile Safari/537.36'`

Working browser userAgent 
`'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'`

Comment: One more data point for Cordova iOS: `"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 17_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148"`

Comment: There is a contradiction in your question: *"I'm getting the response: Uncaught TypeError: map.entries is not a function"*  versus *"I am still able to successfully call map.entries()"*. It cannot be both true: either the function is there or it isn't. If at some point it isn't, then please check what `map` is at the moment of the error.

Comment: After more experimenting, I believe the uncaught error is with for ... of where it doesn't support the MapIterator object for some reason but it does for Arrays and the Map directly, ie. `for (const [key, value] of map)` is fine. But as soon as I use `map.entries`, it throws the not iterable error